# Creating a linked list with a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Here is my struct

```
struct ListItem{

    int data;
    struct ListItem *next;

};
```

Assuming the first node of the linked list will have data = 0, I want to write a for loop that creates a linked list of size 5 but I'm not sure how to work

I tried the following

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    struct ListItem a;
    a.data = 0;


    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
        struct ListItem *pointer = &a;
        struct ListItem nextnode;
        nextnode.data = i;
        a.next = &nextnode;
        pointer = pointer->next;

    }
}
```

But the result is
a.data = 0
and a.next->data = 4

Comment: You are taking the reference to a local (nextnode), doing that is incorrect - you will need to allocate memory for each node that you create (and free it when you're done).  Are you familiar with memory allocation in C?

Comment: You are also setting 'pointer' to the first node in the linked list each time through the loop, so it's not surprising that node 0 points to node 4 (N[0]->N[4]).  The memory management part is the larger concern though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't modify a. Take a temp node starting as a. Make it's next point to the new node and then set temp node to the new node. Also allocate dynamically in heap. Otherwise the memory will get deallocated after every loop run

Comment: I understand why this would work but i'm not sure how to write it in syntax

Comment: node * tempnode = &a
for(int i=1; i<5; i++)
{
node* next=new node();
next->val=i;
tempnode->next=next;
tempnode=next;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ListItem a[5] = { {0, NULL}};
struct ListItem *pointer = &a[0];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    a[i].data = i;
    if(i != 5 -1)
        a[i].next = &a[i+1];
}
```